# Selecting distinct 2 columns combination in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, distinct, distinct-values

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
1   value1    value2    3534
2   value1    value1    8456
3   value1    value2    3566
4   value1    value3    7345
5   value2    value3    6734
```

I need a query to select all the rows with distinct column 2 and 3, for example the output I want for this example will look like this:

```
1   value1    value2    3534
2   value1    value1    8456
4   value1    value3    7345
5   value2    value3    6734
```

i've found a few samples on how to do it but they all select distinct on each column individually.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that the first column is unique, you can do this:

```
SELECT id, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourtable
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY col2, col3
)
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f1c/1)

Answer (score 43):

### Update 1

Better you use this against above.

```
SELECT id, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY col2, col3;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f1c/19)

The reason I am saying is because using CONCAT, I am not getting desired result in ***[this case](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a5c66/2)***. First query is returning me 5 rows however CONCAT is returning me 4 rows which is INCORRECT.

Hope you got my point.

---

Assumed the columns in the table are (id, col2, col3, col4).

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(col2, col3)) as "dummy column", id, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY CONCAT(col2, col3);
```

### OR

```
SELECT id, col2, col3, MIN(col4)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY col2, col3;
```

### [live working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f1c/14)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the columns in the table are `(id, col1, col2, col3)`, you could:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    YourTable yt
JOIN    (
        SELECT  MIN(id) as minid
        FROM    YourTable
        GROUP BY
                col1, col2
        ) filter
ON      filter.minid = yt.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This query makes sure that the combination of column1 and column2 is unique, while selecting the minimum value of column three

```
SELECT col1, col2, MIN(col3)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

THe simplest query for this is

```
SELECT col1, col2, MIN(col3)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the group by method is returning me extra rows, where as explicitly checking each field although longer returns the same no of records as count(Distinct ..)

```
SELECT id, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourtable yt
WHERE id =
(
 SELECT MIN(id)
 FROM yourtable yt1
 WHERE yt.col2 = yt1.col2
 AND yt.col3 = yt1.col3
)
```

Comment: Would be useful if you showed test data where this gives a different answer than the accepted answer. AFAIK, the only reason it would be different is when there are `NULL` values. `DISTINCT` allows columns with `NULL`, but `group by` omits rows with such columns.