# Hiding new column (alias column)

Tags: mysql, hide

I have a mysql table that looks like this:

```
id    col2    col3      col4
1   value1    value2    3534
2   value1    value1    8456
3   value1    value2    3566
4   value1    value3    7345
5   value2    value3    6734
```

What I wanted to do is, select distinct col2+col3 values

```
id    col2    col3      col4
1   value1    value2    3534
2   value1    value1    8456
4   value1    value3    7345
5   value2    value3    6734
```

I used below query, I get desired result as shown ***[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f1c/14).***

```
SELECT distinct(CONCAT(col2, col3)) as "dummy column", id, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY CONCAT(col2, col3);
```

### My question is,

As I don't want to display column "dummy column" in output table, how can I hide the same?

This question is related to SO older question

***[Selecting distinct 2 columns combination in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277251/selecting-distinct-2-columns-combination-in-mysql/11277389#11277389)***

Comment: @MarkByers : its working... see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38f1c/14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you trying the following?

```
SELECT id, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY col2, col3
```

Comment: without that I won't get desired result.

Comment: Why dont you use group by column1, column2...since it wont need the concat and distinct stuff