# Way to filter 2 columns for unique !combinations! with laravel / eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to get all unique combinations of color_code.code and manufacturer_bundle.name that exist. They are connected via a table manufacturer

this is my current code.

```
 $color_codes = ColorCode::select(['color_code.code', 'manufacturer_bundle.name'])->distinct()
  ->leftJoin('manufacturer_bundle', 'color_code.manufacturer_id' , '=' , 'manufacturer_bundle.id')
->get();
```

The **problem** with it, is, that the select returns only those fields, and not actually the models. So I want to be able to do this:

```
$color_code->manufacturer->name
```

which gives me

> Trying to get property of non-object

for completeness:

ColorCode:

```
 Schema::create('color_code', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->index('code');
        $table->integer('manufacturer_id');
        $table->index('manufacturer_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Manufacturer

```
 Schema::create('manufacturer', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->index('name');
        $table->integer('manufacturer_bundle_id')->nullable();
        $table->index(  'manufacturer_bundle_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277251/selecting-distinct-2-columns-combination-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Only eloquent objects can have relationships, not collections.

The results of your query are collections, not Eloquent objects, because you are combining two tables. So of course you cannot "inherit" model relationships for combinations of data. You would have to create a new model for linking color codes with manufacturers for that to work, or find ColorCode from the specified dataset by hand:

```
$color_codes = ColorCode::select(['color_code.code', 'manufacturer_bundle.name'])->distinct()
  ->leftJoin('manufacturer_bundle', 'color_code.manufacturer_id' , '=' , 'manufacturer_bundle.id')
->get();

foreach ($color_codes as $color_data) {
  $color_code = ColorCode::where('code', color_data->code)->first();
  echo $color_code->manufacturer->name;
}
```

Comment: apart from this being ineffective, it wouldn't work. Because  the unique combination constraint is not fullfilled

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `hasManyThrough` relationship. [Laravel Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

In your `ColorCode` model add the following method to define hasManyThrough relationship.
**Note**: Assuming you have `ManufacturerBundle` model for table `manufacturer_bundle` and `Manufacturer` for `manufacturer` table.

```
public function manufacturer_bundle(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(ManufacturerBundle::class,Manufacturer::class);
}
```

Now, in your controller you can use following method to retrieve the `manufacturer_bundle`.

```
$color_codes = ColorCode::with('manufacturer_bundle')->get();
```

Comment: what about the results needing to be distinct? that is needing to be unique combinations

Comment: @Toskan jsu add `distinct()` method