# Get unique rows with combination of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Having this private chat table
[image]

On my message page I want to show latest conversations list. List will be like if am sending message from **pc** to **pc2** and **pc2** sending back to **pc** then it should show only one row.

I tried this query

**SELECT id, col2, col3, col4
   FROM yourtable
   GROUP BY col2, col3;**

[Selecting distinct 2 columns combination in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277251/selecting-distinct-2-columns-combination-in-mysql)

But it's resulting in

[image]

***Update:***

I tried this query

**SELECT * FROM tbl_primessages Where frmid = 3466 OR toid = 3466
GROUP BY frmid, toid ORDER BY `tbl_primessages`.`timestemp`  DESC**

***Update 2***
It should be with the latest time from two

Comment: "then it should show only one row." - which one - and why?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I think the OP just wants the latest message exchanged between each pair of users.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I guess that too. But it would be better, if OP clears that in the question.

Comment: It will be of latest time from those two @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query below used a least/greatest trick to group together messages involving the same pair of users.  Then, we can retain the latest conversation per pair of people.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_primessages t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        LEAST(frmid, toid) AS frmid,
        GREATEST(frmid, toid) AS toid,
        MAX(timestamp) AS latest_ts
    FROM tbl_primessages
    GROUP BY LEAST(frmid, toid), GREATEST(frmid, toid)
) t2
    ON LEAST(t1.frmid, t1.toid)    = t2.frmid AND
       GREATEST(t1.frmid, t1.toid) = t2.toid  AND
       t1.timestamp = t2.latest_ts
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I think you also nead `LEAST/GREATEST` in the ON clause

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Thanks for the edit.  It is particularly painful answering questions like these on a cell phone.

Answer (score 0):

In the SELECT use only fields from the GROUP BY plus some aggregate functions (COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX, etc).

```
SELECT frmid, toid
FROM tbl_primessages
Where frmid = 3466 OR toid = 3466
GROUP BY frmid, toid
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. However you can't use `timestemp` in the ORDER BY clause, because it's not listed in GROUP BY.

Comment: ORDER BY removed, thanks @PaulSpiegel, just copied it from the source query.