# MySQL statement to skip duplicates

Tags: mysql

how could I skip duplicate `AssetId` and get latest `UtcTimeStamp` for each `AssetId`?

I have this statement written and can not figure it out so far.

```
SELECT MobileAsset.[AssetId]
,MobileAsset.[Name] 
,Asset.[AState]
,AssetHistory.[UtcTimeStamp]
FROM [MobileAsset]
inner join Asset on Asset.AssetId = MobileAsset.AssetId 
inner join AssetHistory on AssetHistory.AssetId = Asset.AssetId
where AState != 'scrapped' AND attribute = 'State' and (MobileAsset.AssetId is not null) and OldValue = 'Prestaged' and NewValue = 'In stock'
Order By UtcTimeStamp DESC
```

I get this result:

```
AssetId Name        AState  UtcTimeStamp
3000030 M3000030            2020-01-29 12:11:15.703
3000030 M3000030    In use  2020-01-29 12:11:10.147
3000030 M3000030    In use  2020-01-29 12:09:16.873
3000024 M3000024    In use  2020-01-29 08:38:56.470
```

I want to skip multiple `Asset ID: 3000030`

Answer (score 0):

Use **DISTINCT** keword.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MobileAsset.[AssetId].....
```

Append the DISTINCT keyword for all fields that you need to have distinct values.

Comment: Hello! Thank You for the input, but it seems that it does not work either.

Comment: Maybe this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277251/selecting-distinct-2-columns-combination-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

To simply collect just one of each row you can use something like this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `test`
GROUP BY
    `AssetId`
ORDER BY
    UtcTimeStamp
DESC
```

This will get you this Result

```
3000030     M3000030                    2020-01-29
3000024     M3000024        In use  2020-01-29
```